# Uninstall application in android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to programmatically uninstall a package in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891141/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-uninstall-a-package-in-android)

We can delete package by following steps below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", strPackageName, null);

Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);

startActivity(it);
```

But in this way, Applications Manager's UI will be displayed, my question is how to delete packages silently (without Applications Manager's UI showing).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps your perfectly,

[Install and Uninstall Android applications with PackageInstaller](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98)

Try to googling first, after getting no response. Then, ask here as question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a post on SO that might help you out.

[install / uninstall APKs programmatically (PackageManager vs Intents)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813322/install-uninstall-apks-programmatically-packagemanager-vs-intents)

The last answer gives a tutorial on how to go about doing that.