# How to Programmatically press a button on Install/UnInstall APK Screen in android

Tags: android

Basically I want to install/uninstall an app on my android device from a remote Server.

I send a specific message (such as install or uninstall) from the remote server to my device.

But when the device initiates the process a system genrated Intent will start and shows the message below.

[image]
The OK button must be pressed in order to continue the process.

How can I programmatically press this button from the remote server and continue the process?

Hopefully you understand what I want to explain.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Whenever any of the dialog gets opened then they must be responded by the user.

Comment: If you can send a remote message, will it be possible for you to send keyevents as well? 'adb shell input keyevent xy'

Comment: It's also against security guidelines.

Comment: I think it may possible if the app version is identified by the version number in increasing order. So if the version number is heigher than the previous then using intent.ACTION_DELETE,packageURI the previous can be uninstalled and by using android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, packageURI the new er verson can be installed

Comment: nick again the same dialog will appear if my new APK version is higher then from old one. So how can i initiate  keyevent from Remote server.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is possible only from [play store](https://play.google.com/apps). Click on the recycle bin, but not for external apps.

You can only ask the system to uninstall an app. [Here's the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622867/418903).

Also, as pointed out in the comments:

- When you open a dialog, the choice is user-driven.
- It's against security guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking the same solution for uninstalling any application by sending a SMS from server.
Bellow I'm giving some sample code it may help you.But you need your device as rooted one.
For rooting your device please download s/w from bellow link
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682

The code is

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;

    // boolean isEnabled;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Uninstall();
    }

    private void Uninstall() {
        Process process;
        try {

            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n");
            os.writeBytes("rm -r /system/app/ActionsContentViewExample.apk; \n");
            os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```