# How to delete the old version of app programmatically

Tags: android

I would like to delete the cache and all details of previous versions of an application programmatically when I am installing a new version of an application.  How do you do this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622867/1329126

Comment: @LanceRoberts hahahaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 3):

First determine the current application is old version, then delete it via:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package: your.application.package");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```