# Control the uninstaller action of an Android App from code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to perform some pre-uninstallation activity before the app can be uninstalled. I am new to Android development.
The broadcast receiver I am trying which does not work.
I want to use the Context-registered receivers.
Any Suggestions would help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall any app programmatically. You need app package name.

Manifest(don't required for every API level) :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

Java :

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+"your.packagename.here");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891141/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-uninstall-a-package-in-android/43103385)

To get package name of application

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> packages = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

    ArrayList<String> app_name_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> app_package_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(ResolveInfo resolve_info : packages) {
        try {
            package_name = resolve_info.activityInfo.packageName;
            app_name = (String)pm.getApplicationLabel(
                    pm.getApplicationInfo(package_name
                            , PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            boolean same = false;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < app_name_list.size() ; i++) {
                if(package_name.equals(app_package_list.get(i)))
                    same = true;
            }
            if(!same) {
                app_name_list.add(app_name);
                app_package_list.add(package_name);
            }
            app_name = app_name.toLowerCase();
            package_name = package_name.toLowerCase();
            applicationArray.put(app_name,package_name);
            Log.i("Check", "package = <" + package_name + "> name = <" + app_name + ">");
           //Log.d("APPLICATION_ARRAY", String.valueOf(applicationArray));
        } catch(Exception e) { }
    }
```